# Completing and order using choice fields

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to make it so when an order processed and payment is made, the payment status is changed to complete. At the moment my orders stay on pending consistently.

What should be happening is that the order is completed the page is redirect to home page, cart is emptied and payment status changes to 'Complete'

**Models:**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    PAYMENT_STATUS_PENDING = 'P'
    PAYMENT_STATUS_COMPLETE = 'C'
    PAYMENT_STATUS_FAILED = 'F'

    PAYMENT_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (PAYMENT_STATUS_PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (PAYMENT_STATUS_COMPLETE, 'Complete'),
        (PAYMENT_STATUS_FAILED, 'Failed')
    ]
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    order_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    payment_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=PAYMENT_STATUS_CHOICES, default=PAYMENT_STATUS_PENDING
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
    
    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        order_items = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in order_items])
        return total
    
    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        order_items = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in order_items])
        return total
```

**views:**

```
 if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, payment_status='P')
        #TODO: add float field?
        total = data['form']['total']
        order.order_id = order_id


        if total == order.get_cart_total:
            order.payment_status = 'C'
        order.save()
```

**JS**

```
  var total = '{{order.get_cart_total}}'
    
        var form = document.getElementById('form')
    
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            console.log('Form Submitted..')
            document.getElementById('form-button').classList.add('hidden');
            document.getElementById('payment-info').classList.remove('hidden');
        })

        document.getElementById('make-payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){
            submitFormData()
        })

       function submitFormData(){
            console.log('Payment button clicked')

            var userFormData = {
                'first_name':null,
                'last_name':null,
                'email':null,
                'total':total, 
            }
      
            var url = '/process_order/'

            fetch(url, {
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
                },
                body:JSON.stringify({'form':userFormData, 'shipping':shippingInfo}),
            })
            .then((response) =>{
                response.json()
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log('Success:', data);
                alert('Transaction completed');
                window.location.href = "{% url 'home' %}"
            })
        }
    </script
```

> 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

had to change both values into floats.

total = **float(** data['form']['total'] **)**

if total == **float(** order.get_cart_total **)**